# Prove whether or not there exists a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

$f:\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, such that $f(1)=7$.

What I wrote:

Let $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=7$.

Therefore $f(1)=f(1+0)=f(1)+f(0)=7$. This follows from the definition of a homomorphism.

Is this correct?

A second one:

$f:\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, such that $f(2)=1$.
I basically did the same thing as above, is this correct? It seems far too easy...

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ has more that $2$ elements, so giving $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ is not enough to specify a function $f\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. You need to define $f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For your second question, if it was possible you would have $1=f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)=2f(1)$. Does that seem possible in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Remember that botb 1 and 7 are generators of your ring

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, homomorphism maps identity to identity. But i dont think this one does.

Comment: This question is tagged "group-theory", not "ring-theory".

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that it's not "ring-theory"?

Comment: Since the OP clamed he could separately define $f(0)=0$ and $f(2)=1$, I thought you meant that he should have put $f(1)=1$ (which is not the case, for group homomorphism). Now I see that you actually meant that a group homomorphism such that $f(2)=1$ must have $f(0)=5$. The argument is ok, sorry (not written at its best, perhaps).

Comment: Which still gives contradiction. Thanks for the reply